# Replicate Django Admin's "add" button

Tags: django, django-admin

Let's say I have the following two models, each with their own `form` to create model records.

For example:

```
Business_Client Model:
   busName field - CharField
   mainContact field - ForeignKey(Contacts)

Contacts Model:
    firstName field - CharField
    lastName field - CharField
```

When the user wants to create a new business, they will have to select a "Main Contact" from a drop down menu. However, if the contact is not in the list, they have to create *that* record first, then come back, and **re**-start creating the `business` record again.

The admin interface makes this easy by having the little `+` button beside the drop down menu which takes you to the `Contact` form, you fill it out, hit `Save` which then brings you *back* to the `Business` form, *with* the `mainContact` field already selected to your newly created `Contact` record.

How do I do this!?! I have been searching around Google and am coming up short. Anyone have some good links/tutorials that would get me going?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've never done it, but thinking about it:

You have a view

```
/add/business/
```

with a field for name, and a field for contact (with a little plus beside it). The plus is simply a link that creates new popup window via javascript that points to

```
/add/contact/
```

and has a javascript callback. When the form is submitted, validated and put into the DB, the window closes and the id/name is passed back to the original form and auto entered in the field.

This seems to be how the django admin does it. You can look at the widget that the django admin uses yourself:

https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L218

The render function that has the html:

https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L249

which shows that it's simply an anchor link with an onlick javascript popup pointing to the relvant add view. Once the form is submitted the values are passed back.

https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js#L55

Comment: I think your line numbers are no longer valid. They point to what looks like utterly unrelated code.